# Asp.net MVC - access Views from another solution/ Shared directory over the network

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

Hi I am Trying to separate Views , controller and model in 3 different solutions 
And trying to access views from a shared directory means trying to access views in C drive and my solution is in D drive.

This is for a multi tenant application

Answer (score 0):

You can separate models and controllers into another project. Your views need to be part of the main mvc application. Just make sure you add mvc using nuget to each and keep things together with namespaces and it should be fine.